# Is it possible for a single restful web service to consume JSON,csv,xml?

Tags: web-services, rest

Am tryin to consume json,csv and xml in a restful webservice? But when i go throughed many links i found its possible by setting it in the header information. But am not sure or pretty much clear wit those concepts..It would be great if somebody helps me out..Thanks in advance..

Comment: If you use a framework, most will have content negotiation built-in or let you detect it.

Comment: @Martin: Thanks..but am able to detect which content type and i tried converting the JSon from the request and set it to a plain POJO with getters & setters without any annotations.Now am not able to manipulate with those objects. I get an exception : [12/13/11 14:09:44:450 IST] 00000024 SystemErr     R org.jboss.resteasy.spi.BadRequestException: Could not find message body reader for type: class of content type: application/json;charset="UTF-8"   Thanks in advance..

Comment: `application/json;charset="UTF-8"` try removing the `;charset="UTF-8"` part. It seems the header parser is doing dumb checking and not properly parsing the content-type.

Comment: @Martin: It didnt work out Martin. Am unable to remove the content type. And again if i set the charet UTF-8 ,it throws the same exception. Can you let me know where am wrong.Thanks!

Comment: @martin: the exact problem is am able to convert the json to java objects(without annotations,plain class with getters,setters) in the preprocessor but when i try to manipulate the java objects in a another class it throws that exception.It would be great if you can help me out.Thanks!!!

Comment: Sorry haven't done java in a long time. the exception you have pasted a few comments before says a body reader could not be found for the provided content-type.

Answer (score 3):

Look at [Content-Type](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17) and [Accept](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.1).

The concept is called [content negotiation.](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec12.html) .